# testing application server response

Tags: java, unit-testing, open-source, continuous-integration

My application has a two completly seperated application servers.
They speak with each others in various models for instance.
A puts a file in a Folder
B listen and reads the file, create a response FILE in a new Folder
A picks up the "response" file.

Same thing with JMS:
A publish something
B will listen and Reply

Now, I want to test this with application A only so that I have some sort of dynamic stub simulating B that is triggered when my real application A is creating the file or the Topic.

Any framworks that can support this?

I saw Mactor, but it looks like a dead project, any other sugegstions?

Comment: Will you simulate the file system as seen from A?

Comment: Correct. I want some sort of simulator engine to replicate the complex work done by B.

Comment: Then consider mócking up file system access in A.

Comment: Yes, but since in Application A the Flow to Send the File and the Flow to receive the file from App B are disconnected, Idealy, I want to mockup B alltogether rather than mocking specifically this part of the flow or the other. So it's more level of end-to-end testing rather than unit testing.

Comment: For this to be manageable you should reconsider where you want to have the cut between real A and mocked non-A.  It appears you want a mock B in a live file system.  I would suggest having a mock filesystem+B.

Comment: B not alwasy can be tested. I want to test A only, B is a black-box for me. I need some sort of dynamic stub that can enqueue Messages of JMS or listen on folders. From A point of view, whether B is there a stub, the process should be identical.

Comment: I disagree with @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen. The natural place to put the real/mock break here is between the servers, so what you're testing is a complete server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this requirment, to perform relativly good level of integration testing with external system we have no control over. We used Jmeter.
Jmeter has the capability to listen on a JMS resource, wait for a request and act upon it, we used a set of stubs to represents the logic of the real system that way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a mock server for B based on the real code for B. I would use that to create your mock instance for testing purposes.

Comment: Bringing up B is an issue. It's not always possible, which is why I want to have some sort of dynamic stub that simulates B.

Comment: Instead of bring up a full B instance, can you run a cut down version, possibly on the same host as A or another free host.

Comment: No. It is owned by a second company and I have no control on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need a framework for this. You need to be able to drive files and JMS from inside a JUnit (or whatever) test, but that is a simple matter of coding.

You can then write tests that do things like:

1. Create a file in A's input directory
2. Wait for a file to appear in A's output directory
3. Validate the contents of the file

For more complicated series of interactions, simply extend the sequence with more action - wait - validation cycles.

Perhaps you are thinking that you need a framework that can react to different events coming from A, so that you don't need to write sequences of interactions out explicitly. I would say this is a bad idea. A test should be an explicit sequence, so it's clear what it's doing.